# ASP.NET Codefirst relationships

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, code-first

I made this relationships in codefirst but it shows exactly this error that shows in this image. I upload my models for you and you can download it from [here](http://static.persiandota.com/models.zip)[4kb]. what is this error? why it shows this? I want to have all my categories in posts table. so what is way? who can help?

[image]

someone tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

By convention in Entity Framework, deleting an entity will delete anything that is linked to that antity. In your case that means deleting cat1 will delete every cat2, cat3 and post that is referencing cat 1.

Your problem occurs because you specify WillCascadeOnDelete(true) on the posts map that you also want a post to automatically trigger a deletion of the cat1, cat2 and cat3 that the post references which can cause a partial or complete wipe of the database (posts delete categories that delete posts that delete categories and so on).

To fix it you need to remove your WillCascadeOnDelete(true)-mappings from postMap.

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.cat1)
    .WithMany(t => t.posts)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.excat1);
this.HasRequired(t => t.cat2)
    .WithMany(t => t.posts)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.excat2);
this.HasRequired(t => t.cat3)
    .WithMany(t => t.posts)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.excat3);
```

You need to add WillCascadeOnDelete(false) to the categories higher up the tree to your cat2Map and cat3Map.

cat2Map:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.cat1)
    .WithMany(t => t.cat2s)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.excat1)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

cat3Map:

```
this.HasRequired(t => t.cat1)
    .WithMany(t => t.cat3s)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.excat1)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); <-- Add this
this.HasRequired(t => t.cat2)
    .WithMany(t => t.cat3s)
    .HasForeignKey(d => d.excat2)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false); <-- Add this
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answring. but now it has this error : The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_dbo.cat3_dbo.cat2_excat2". The conflict occurred in database "DbPro", table "dbo.cat3", column 'excat2'.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: When you turn off cascading delete you have to manually make sure that everything that references the object you are deleting gets deleted first, or updated to reference a different post. I can't test or verify your new problem since I'm not at a computer anymore.